# Bianchi Identity in Chern's book

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-bundles

I'm reading Chern's book "complex manifolds without potential theory".

In chapter 5 he claims the following: Let $E\to M$ be a vector bundle, $D$ a connection, $\omega$ the corresponding connection form and $\Omega := D\omega = d\omega -\omega \land \omega$ the curvature form. Then he claims that taking exterior derivative for the equation $\Omega = d\omega - \omega\land \omega$ yields: $$D\Omega = d\Omega + \Omega \land \omega - \omega \land \Omega = 0 $$which is Bianchi identity.

I'm not familiar with these notations, and therefore struggling to understand this equation:

1. Shouldn't $D\Omega$ be just $d\Omega + \Omega \land \omega$, by the definition of exterior covariant derivative $D\left(\alpha \otimes s 
    \right) = d\alpha \otimes s + \left( -1\right)^\left|\alpha\right|\alpha\land Ds$?
2. Why is the RHS equals zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer in reverse order.

First, recall the definition of curvature: $\Omega = d\omega-\omega\wedge\omega$, so that
$$d\omega = \Omega + \omega\wedge\omega.$$
If you differentiate
$$\Omega - d\omega + \omega\wedge\omega = 0,$$
you get
$$0=d\Omega + (\Omega+\omega\wedge\omega)\wedge\omega - \omega\wedge(\Omega+\omega\wedge\omega) = d\Omega +\Omega\wedge\omega-\omega\wedge\Omega,$$
since the $\omega\wedge\omega\wedge\omega$ terms cancel.

Second, $\Omega$ is a $2$-form with values in $\text{Hom}(E,E)$, so you have to use the formula (5.28) to define the covariant derivative.

Comment: Thank you! I copletely missed the fact that the value of $\Omega$ is in the endomorphism bundle. So just to make sure I understand, this is in fact a formula for extending a connection on $E$ to a connection on $\operatorname{End}\left(E\right)$, i.e. a map $\Gamma\left(\operatorname{End}\left(E\right)\right)\to\Gamma\left(T^{*}M\otimes\operatorname{End}\left(E\right)\right)$ so that the formula for the covariant exterior derivative is the usual one but for this extension of the connection?

Comment: So you have to use the connection form $\omega$ (which gives a connection on $E$) to induce a connection on $E^*$ and then on $\text{Hom}(E,E) \cong E^*\otimes E$. Is that what you're saying?

Comment: yes, and then I'm asking if the formula in 5.28 you mentioned is just the usual formula $D\left(\alpha \otimes s 
 \right) = d\alpha \otimes s + \left( -1\right)^\left|\alpha\right|\alpha\land Ds$ applied to this specific connection

Comment: Yes. If you write out a basic section of Hom as a tensor product, you'll see that.

Comment: excellent, thank you so much!